# JS key rename with defineProperty won't work in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
Object.prototype.prefixKeys = function (prefix) {
 for (var key in this) 
   this.hasOwnProperty(key) 
   && Object.defineProperty(this, prefix + key, {value: this[key]})
   && delete this[key]
}
```

Code above works as expected in chrome console. But just removes keys in Node v6.10.2. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which error message do you get?

Comment: No any errors, just empty object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prefixed keys still exist on the object, but if you want them to show up when you, say `console.log(obj)`, then you need to make the properties `enumerable`:

```
Object.prototype.prefixKeys = function (prefix) {
 for (var key in this) 
   this.hasOwnProperty(key) 
   && Object.defineProperty(this, prefix + key, {
     value: this[key],
     enumerable: true
   })
   && delete this[key]
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is genius, as simple as that.

Comment: You've saved me, many thanks! 
P.S.: surprised that properties are not enumerable by default...